# Two estimations in analytic number theory

Tags: analytic-number-theory

I want to show the following two estimation:
$$
\sum_{p|n}\frac{\log p}{p}=O(\log\log n)
$$
And
$$
\sum_{p|n}\frac1p=O(\log\log\log n)
$$

First assume $$n=p_1^{\alpha_1}...p_s^{\alpha_s}$$ then the first can be rewritten as:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^s\frac{\log p_i}{p_i}
$$

I think i should bulid some connections between s and n, and could i do the following?
$$
\sum_{i=1}^s\frac{\log p_i}{p_i}=O(\sum_{i=1}^s\frac{1}{i})
$$

If this is true, why?

Comment: You should say that the $p$s in your sums are restricted to the primes which divide $n$.  That is implicit in your rewrites but it is better to bring it up explicitly

Comment: @RossMillikan just primes

Comment: The largest your sums can be is when $n$ is a primorial.  I would assume that it is and use the prime number theorem to estimate the size of the primes.  No guarantees.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only ingredient needed is the elementary (Chebysev estimates) $Ak\log k < q_k < Bk\log k, k \ge 2$ where $q_1=2, q_2=3,...$ is the sequence of primes. This implies:

$\frac{1}{q_k} < \frac{A_1}{k \log k}, k \ge 2$ and $\frac{\log q_k}{q_k} < \frac{A_2}{k}, k \ge 1$.

Also $\frac{\log x}{x}$ is decreasing for $x \ge 3$ so if $p \ge q_k, \frac{\log p}{p} < \frac{A_2}{k}, k \ge 2$

If $n=p_1^{\alpha_1}...p_s^{\alpha_s}$ (in increasing order of the primes) we have:

$\log n=\sum_{k=1}^s\alpha_k \log p_k \ge s\log 2$ since $\alpha_k \ge 1, \log p_k \ge \log 2$, hence :

$s \le C\log n$

Then using that $p_k \ge q_k$ we get that:

$\sum_{p|n}\frac{\log p}{p} \le \sum_{k=1}^{C\log n}\frac{A_2}{k} \le A_3  \log \log n$

$\sum_{p|n}\frac{1}{p} \le \sum_{k=2}^{C\log n}\frac{A_1}{k\log k} \le A_4 \log \log  \log n$, so we are done!

Comment: Great thanks for your help!

Comment: happy to be of help

Comment: wait a moment! I thought i got the second implied statement, but i found i got wrong, can u explained more detailed?

Comment: $\sum_{k=2}^{C\log n}\frac{1}{k\log k}$ is estimated by $\int_2^{C\log n}\frac{dx}{x\log x}$ and the latter is less than $\log \log (C\log n)=\log \log \log n+C_1$

Comment: ah I’m so sorry to confuse u, i know how to estimate this sum, the whole problem is how to get \frac{\log q_k}{q_k}<\frac{A_2}{k}

Comment: Since $q_k < Bk\log k$ we get $\log q_k \le B_1\log k$ (we can absorb $\log \log k$ as it is much smaller) use then $q_k >Ak\log k$ to get $1/q_k < A_1/(k\log k)$ and multiply

Comment: very thanks!!!! And i also get an idea from my notes written on the class, maybe i will show this solution under this problem

Answer (score 0):

Take the first as an example: from what we have done, it suffices to estimate:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^s\frac{\log p_i}{p_i}
$$
Classify $p_1,...,p_s$as follows：
$p_1,...,p_{r_0}\leq\log n$，$p_{r_0+1},...,p_s>\log n$, so:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{r_0}\frac{\log p_i}{p_i}\leq\sum_{p\leq\log n}\frac{\log p}{p}\leq\log\log n+O(1)
$$

We then estimate how large the $r-r_0$ is :
$$
(\log n)^{r-r_0}<p_{r_0+1}...p_s\leq n\to r-r_0\leq\frac{\log n}{\log\log n}
$$
So,
$$
\sum_{i=r_0+1}^s\frac{\log p_i}{p_i}\leq\frac{\log\log n}{\log n}\times\frac{\log n}{\log\log n}=1
$$
I.e
$$
\sum_{i=1}^s\frac{\log p_i}{p_i}=O(\log\log n)
$$